# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'object'

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop

I have a for statement which goes through a given number of events or in this case, parameters. Inside the for, I have an if statement which check if a certain parameter exists and if that parameter exists, do something and so on and so forth.

```
for (int i = 1; i < eventToHandle.Parameters.Count; i++)
{
    if (eventToHandle.Parameters.ContainsKey($"DirectoryOne{i}") && 
        eventToHandle.CustomParameters[$"DirectoryOne{i}"])
    {
        DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(eventToHandle.Parameters[$"DirectoryOne{i}"].ToString());
        FileInfo[] files = rootDir.GetFiles();
        DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = rootDir.GetDirectories();
    }
```

I am getting the error which says I cannot use '&&' on bool and object. What would be a good solution in this case? Maybe the if statement with the '&&' is not good at all to use in this case?

Comment: What is `eventToHandle.CustomParameters[$"DirectoryOne{i}"]`?  What are you trying to check in your `if` condition?

Comment: Can you give us some example values for `eventToHandle.CustomParameters[$"DirectoryOne{i}"]`? You might want to `bool.Parse()` them

Comment: I think you wanted to check `eventToHandle.CustomParameters.ContainsKey($"DirectoryOne{i}")` instead. What you have there does not evaluate to a `bool`, but an `object`.

Comment: Maybe check for null on object, if (eventToHandle.Parameters.ContainsKey($"DirectoryOne{i}") && 
        eventToHandle.CustomParameters[$"DirectoryOne{i}"] !=null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code wants to ensure that the value is safe for a call of `ToString`, so you should check if it's `null` or not.

Since you are getting the string from a dictionary after a check that the object exists, use `TryGetValue` to avoid making multiple searches through the dictionary:

```
object dir;
if (eventToHandle.Parameters.TryGetValue($"DirectoryOne{i}", out dir) && dir != null) {
    DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(dir.ToString());
    FileInfo[] files = rootDir.GetFiles();
    DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = rootDir.GetDirectories();
}
```

Comment: `&& dir is string directory` could be helpful too if the value is a `string`.

Comment: This was a lot of help, i managed to work out a solution with some modifications. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't just use an object with the `&&` operator, because it operates with `bool` values. You have to check if it's not null (`!= null`).

You should also use [Directory.Exists()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if that directory exists.

```
using System.IO;

for (int i = 1; i < eventToHandle.Parameters.Count; i++)
{
    if (eventToHandle.Parameters.ContainsKey($"DirectoryOne{i}") &&
        eventToHandle.CustomParameters[$"DirectoryOne{i}"] != null && 
        Directory.Exists(eventToHandle.CustomParameters[$"DirectoryOne{i}"].ToString()))
    {
        DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(eventToHandle.Parameters[$"DirectoryOne{i}"].ToString());
        FileInfo[] files = rootDir.GetFiles();
        DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = rootDir.GetDirectories();
    }
```

Comment: Won't compile...

Comment: Why would it not compile?

Comment: You know that, since you have updated the code. Still, this code could throw a null reference exception.

Comment: I added the null check, for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading it right the 'if' statement has 2 parts. First, check the key exists (left-hand side of &&) and then check the key does not map to a null value (right-hand side of &&). The && compares 2 bools, but the right hand side isn't of type bool, it's of type Object. To check if that object reference isn't null you have to change `eventToHandle.CustomParameters[$"DirectoryOne{i}"]` to `eventToHandle.CustomParameters[$"DirectoryOne{i}"] != null`